# Where should I have users save the images that they made on my app

Tags: android

My users make custom images on my app and I am unsure what directory I should use when they save. Should I use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?

Comment: You can either create a new folder for your App pictures in the External Storage Directory itself; or in the public directory -> Pictures -> YourApp; or in DCIM -> YourApp

Answer (score 0):

Basically `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is part of Content Resolver which allow you to read and write resource from your user device. You need to ask yourself wether it is good to save their image into device. You could save your image in private or public which still decided by you. There is internal and external storage, wether you need all image to be deleted when your app is deleted or you don't want other app access the photo you user created use internal storage otherwise use external storage.Take a look on this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) which take you step by step to understand why, which,how to save file into your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a directory of your own app in the internal storage of the device and store all the pictures made from your app there.

You can make the directory using

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "<app name>");
if(!directory.exists){
directory.mkdirs;
}
```

And then store the pictures in this path

```
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
 n = generator.nextInt(n);
String name = "<image name>"+n+".jpg";
File pictureFile = new File(directory, name);
pictureFile.createNewFile();
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
   out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Another good way to pick names for files is by time, just like the camera app does, that way you'd never have two files with the same name, regardless of how many new files you create.

Comment: Yes. That is another possibility.